# ListBox menu issues

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{             
    if (listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    { 
        return; 
    } 

    //string filePath = (listBoxFiles.SelectedItem).ToString(); 
    int index = listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex; 
    listBoxFiles.Items.RemoveAt(index); 
} 

<ListBox Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,35,0,0" Name="listBoxFiles" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="323" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">

                            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_DoubleClick" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete File" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"></MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
                </ListBox>
```

1. why each pressing on item in the Listbox change it's status from selected (color blue) to not selected and if file is selected and i press on an empty space on the Listbox the file remained selected ?
2. i implement function that if i press right click on item in the Listbox and in the menu press Delete the item removed from my List box but this happen only if the file not selected before, i mean if i press on item in the Listbox and than right click and remove the file remined in the Listbox and not deleted

Comment: I'm not trying to be an asshat, because you sound like quite a curious developer (which is great :D).  However, I'd recommend spending some time on an english-speaking forum to enhance your english. It's just really hard to solve a problem when the problem is hard to understand.

Comment: OK let me try again, you can see my function, i have application with listbox, i can add files into my listbox and i want to have the option to remove files from the listbox (i already have CLEAR button who clear all the list box but i want to option to remove one file from many), when i press right click on item in my list box and than choose Delete (from my menu) the file delete but if i press on item in my listbox with the left button (and than it become blue) and than right click and delete the file did not delete and i want to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you select an item by left clicking, and then you right click on the same item, it actually deselects the item.

This is the designed behavior because you have SelectionMode="Multiple" on your listbox, which defaults to the following behavior:

- Left Click = Selects the item.
- Right Click = Deselects the item.

Because the right click deselects the item, whenever you right click to access the context menu, the item will be deselected first, then the context menu will appear.

Then, you no longer have an item selected, so the delete will not delete anything.

To solve this, simply set the SelectionMode="Single", and now right clicking will no longer deselect the item, and your delete will work as expected.